# What is the type of a generic tuple which is also polymorphic in the number of fields?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, tuples

So the inital type is simply a generic `Pair` and I want to be able to extend this `Pair` with additional fields:

```
type Pair<A, B> = [A, B];

const foo = <A, B, R extends Pair<A, B>>(...args: R): R => args;

foo(123, "foo"); // well-typed
foo(123, "foo", true); // type error but should be well-typed
foo(123, "foo", true, "bar"); // type error but should be well-typed
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgSwE4B4CCAaKAhAfFAXigG1McBdAbgFgAoOgYwHsA7AZ2CgDMmnCp0WbFgBKUCAA9gEFgBM2sRKjJ5cACgB0WuEgDmbAFxQRASiNiC+Hfpr1aPJmoCMAJgDMWAEQPPJ2w+d3Lx8sYCQAVwg-OgDXDyhvXk9QiIgvACMdX0ogA)

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) in TypeScript have a fixed `length` attribute of a [numeric literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) type.  (This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#17765](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17765)).  So any `Pair<A, B>` will have length `2`:

```
type PairLength = Pair<any, any>['length']; // 2
```

A [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) of the form `R extends Pair<A, B>` means that `R` must be a subtype of `Pair<A, B>`.  Specifically `R` must have a `length` property assignable to `2`.  So you won't be able to assign `[number, string, boolean]` (whose `length` is `3`) or `[number, string, boolean, string]` (whose `length` is `4`) to `Pair<A, B>`.

---

I'd suggest that. instead of fixed-length tuples, you use [*open-ended* tuples, with a final *rest element*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types).  For example:

```
type PairOrLonger<A, B> = [A, B, ...any[]];
```

The type `PairOrLonger<A, B>` is an array of length 2 or greater, whose first element of type `A` and whose second element is of type `B`, and with zero or more elements of type `any` after that.  If you inspect it, the `length` property is just `number` (TypeScript doesn't have [range types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480) so you can't say "at least `2`" as a type):

```
type PairOrLongerLength = PairOrLonger<any, any>['length']; // number
```

Then we can use that in `foo` and everything works because we no longer have a fixed-length constraint on `R`:

```
const foo = <A, B, R extends PairOrLonger<A, B>>(...args: R): R => args;

foo(123, "foo");
foo(123, "foo", true);
foo(123, "foo", true, "bar");
```

---

Please note that `A` and `B` are serving no purpose in `foo` because they are not being inferred.  You would do just as well with a function like

```
const bar = <R extends [any, any, ...any[]]>(...args: R): R => args;
bar(123, "foo");
bar(123, "foo", true);
bar(123, "foo", true, "bar");
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgSwE4B4CCAaKAhAfFAXigG1McBdAbgFgAoO0SWRJAGQgDsBzYAC0ObIUcDiCwiQuYgHIANpx69pVKAHpVUAEx0G4aPGQB5NgHtuEVGTwDSWbFgB0TicXJUdtRvpbHWZrhbs3HwCBki+-hbCouKiUnIKfMqUahocAK4AtgBGFh50AMZmAM7AUABmJiYC6HZYAEpQEAAewJwAJsWC4abmlna4uAAUTg5wSFzFAFxQ9QCUM40E+OOTNPS0lSZDAIyaAMxYAERbR3PrW7sHx6dYwEjpEOd0l3uHUCdVR3cPEMfZ4zO60KJTKAKQNUaLTaHE6JAksTEUFGLjcwxRE2mswWs0IK0x63BV3enxMQLoRLeNy+P0ez1olOuH1uUHuj3+gPOUCAA)

Comment: I used `A`/`B` to enforce at least a tuple. `any` does the trick too but personally I still consider the type vars to be more descriptive. I didn't know that the rest syntax exists at the type level in TS. After years of experience in JS it is kind of weird to be a rookie again :D Thanks!

Comment: But what do they describe?  They get inferred as `unknown` even if `R` has more specific types.  If I really wanted `A` and `B` in there I'd probably do [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgSwE4HkkBkD2A7A5hJAHgEEAaKAIQD4oBeKAbTMvIDp25sQGBdHgbgCwAKADGOAM7AoAM0yY6UQgCUoEAB7AI2ACYTYiVBhz4izauWKLlDAAw9yFawwCMPKgAp2rOElwSALihlAEog1VoaX38hYTlMDxcAJgBmcgAiePSQ2PjE1Iys8mAkAFcIHJE85LSoTPl04rKIDIAjX2zYkSA) so at least the default values of `A` and `B` correspond to the types you pass in.  But that's up to you of course

Comment: They are indeed inferred as `unknown`. However, having a Hindley/Milner background `[A, B]` as an annotation is more descriptive to me regarding the intended use of the type than `[any, any]`. Highly opinionated of course.